# using regex in powershell script to replace value of a key/value tags

Tags: regex, powershell, replace, replaceall

using powershell script, I need to update some values inside an xml file. The xml is a list of keys and values.

More specifically i need to look for the key "servername" and update the relevant value tag with the $myservername. Also to look for the key "serverport" and update the relevant value tag with $myport.

how can this be done using powershell scripting?

i thought of using simple regex replace command as follows

```
$myservername = "some-server"
$myport = "8888"
$localFile = "C:\_Temp\Files\20190822115503\Manifest.xml"
$content = (Get-Content $localFile) 


$newcontent = $content -replace '"<Key>servername</Key>\s*<Value>(value1)</Value>"', $myservername


$newcontent = $content -replace '"<Key>serverport</Key>\s*<Value>(value1)</Value>"', $myport
```

The following is just a partial block of the xml file:

```
    <Properties> 
       <ManifestProperty ValueType="string">
         <Key>servername</Key>
         <Value>value1</Value>
       </ManifestProperty>
       <ManifestProperty ValueType="string">
         <Key>serverport</Key>
         <Value>value2</Value>
       </ManifestProperty>
    </Properties>
```

We need to search for the "key" and then replace the "value"

Comment: as far as i can tell there is NO `-ReplaceAll` parameter for an array. where did you get that?

Comment: have you tried to access the items via XML? if that sample is valid XML you can address the items and make changes directly.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey you are right. i edited the question. but anyway there should be a way to update all maybe by using "match" command?!

Comment: if you convert the XML file [or string] into an object, you should be able to address the items. perhaps by iterating thru the array of object OR by using XPath to access & modify the data. ///// however, until you post a valid, reasonably accurate xml string or file, no one can help you with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the file into PowerShell as an XmlDocument object, you can do the following:

```
$myservername = "some-server"
$myport = "8888"
$xml = [xml](Get-Content C:\temp\xml.xml)
$xml.SelectNodes("//Properties/ManifestProperty[Key = 'servername']") |
    Foreach-Object {
        $_.Value = $myservername
    }
$xml.SelectNodes("//Properties/ManifestProperty[Key = 'serverport']") |
    Foreach-Object {
    $_.Value = $myport
    }
$xml.Save("C:\Temp\xml.xml")
```

Accessing the properties of an XML object is going to be more reliable than regex replace.

**Explanation:**

The code converts the contents of `C:\temp\xml.xml` into an XmlDocument object using the `[xml]` type accelerator. The `SelectNodes()` method uses an XPath to find any child element of `Properties` with a `ManifestProperty` element that contains a `Key` node. The node must contain the text `servername` or text `serverport`. Just in case the method returns multiple nodes, the results are piped into a `Foreach-Object` to update all values.

- `//Properties/ManifestProperty[Key = 'servername']` finds all `ManifestProperty` elements that are a child of the `Properties` element and contain at least one child element named `Key` with a value of `servername`.

---

If you must use regex to replace the text strings, which I don't recommend, you can do the following:

```
$myservername = "some-server"
$myport = "8888"
$xml = Get-Content xml.xml -Raw
$xml = $xml -replace "(?s)(?<=<Key>servername</Key>.*?<Value>)value1(?=</Value>)",$myservername
$xml = $xml -replace "(?s)(?<=<Key>serverport</Key>.*?<Value>)value2(?=</Value>)",$myport
```

**Regex Replace Explanation:**

- `Get-Content xml.xml -Raw`: Reads the contents of the file as one string. This is useful because we need to match on multiple lines. Removing the `-Raw` switch, reads the file into PowerShell as an array. With the array output, we can't use regex to read behind or ahead.
- `(?s)`: This is the single line modifier. It allows for the regex `.` to match any newline characters. This is particularly useful for matching across multiple lines.
- `(?<=<Key>servername</Key>.*?<Value>)`: Performs a positive lookbehind assertion `(?<=)` for the literal match `<Key>servername</Key>`, 0 or more characters matched ungreedily, and literal match `<Value>`.
- `value1`: Literal match
- `(?=</Value>)`: Performs a positive lookahead assertion for literal match `</Value>`.

Below is another way to do regex replace using capture groups:

```
$myservername = "some-server"
$myport = "8888"
$xml = Get-Content xml.xml -Raw
$xml = $xml -replace "(?s)(?<NameKey><Key>servername</Key>.*?<Value>)value1(?<NameValue></Value>)","`${NameKey}$myservername`${NameValue}"
$xml = $xml -replace "(?s)(?<PortKey><Key>serverport</Key>.*?<Value>)value2(?<PortValue></Value>)","`${PortKey}$myport`${PortValue}"
```

**Regex Replace Explanation:**

- `Get-Content xml.xml -Raw`: Reads the contents of the file as one string. This is useful because we need to match on multiple lines. Removing the `-Raw` switch, reads the file into PowerShell as an array. With the array output, we can't use regex to read behind or ahead.
- `(?s)`: This is the single line modifier. It allows for the regex `.` to match any newline characters. This is particularly useful for matching across multiple lines.
- `(?<PortKey><Key>serverport</Key>.*?<Value>)`: `(?<PortKey>)` creates a capture group called `PortKey`. Everything matching within the parentheses would be included in that capture. `serverport` matches literally. `.*?` is a lazy match of 0 or more characters. `<Value>` matches literally.
- `value2`: Literal match
- `(?<PortValue></Value>)`: Capture group called `PortValue` for everything that matches within the parentheses. `</Value>` is a literal match.
- `` "`${PortKey}$myport`${PortValue}" ``: This is the replacement string. Note the double quotes surrounding the expression so that `$myport` will be interpolated. `${PortKey}` and `${PortValue}` is the syntax required to access the capture groups. The backtick character is used to escape the `$` in those capture group references because we do not want PowerShell to interpolate them.

You don't usually need to name your capture groups. However, since one of the captures is numeric, that can cause problems accessing the default capture groups. The first capture group would be accessed by `$1`. Since `$myport` is a number, then `` `$1$myport `` will be evaluated as `$18888` and the regex match will not have a capture group named `18888`. So naming the capture groups, adds better predictability.